# Blazor WASM: Blank Page - TypeError Failed to fetch; undefined TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: blazor, kubernetes-ingress, blazor-webassembly

I am deploying a Blazor WASM page to an AWS kubernetes cluster using a CI/CD pipeline.
After the pipeline has deployed this page, it performs UI tests using Playwright.
These were running successfully in the past.

Now I set-up tls termination using an ingress controller, and the web server is behind that ingress controller. (Before, the web server was directly reachable through a load balancer service.)
After these changes, the Playwright-Tests often fail. The web page remains blank, and the console reports fetching errors:

```
Request failed, reason: net::ERR_FAILED URL: https://myurl.com/_framework/System.Text.Json.dll
console.error at https://myurl.com/_framework/System.Text.Json.dll:0:0: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
Error: TypeError Failed to fetch; undefined TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ut.loadResourceWithoutCaching (https://myurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:49765)
    at ut.loadResourceWithCaching (https://myurl.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:49496)
```

Although chrome reports fetching errors, when I look into the ingress-controller logs, it seems as if the files have been transmitted successfully:

```
172.31.22.142 - - [19/Oct/2022:14:17:13 +0000] "GET /_framework/System.Text.Json.dll HTTP/2.0" 200 97900 "https://myurl.com/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/107.0.5304.18 Safari/537.36" 40 0.053 [build-pr1289-container-name-web-5002] [] 172.31.18.225:80 97900 0.052 200 97a336ce1e2f4cfb775437cf583fc621
172.31.22.142 - - [19/Oct/2022:14:18:11 +0000] "GET /_framework/System.Text.Json.dll HTTP/2.0" 200 97900 "https://myurl.com/dashboard" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/107.0.5304.18 Safari/537.36" 40 0.002 [build-pr1289-container-name-web-5002] [] 172.31.18.225:80 97900 0.000 200 66a4a2b9f804c882453a13685cb8771b
```

It is not always the same file that has fetching errors, but always they are caused at the blazor.webassembly.js initialization that loads dll's and other files.

Using the website manually usually works well. (I have observed the error only a few times.)

Is there maybe a misconfiguration in the ingress-setup, or the blazor server?
Or is it possible, that the blazor server/kestrel is not yet fully initialized (we run the test after the deployment has finished)?

I am using the Microsoft AspNetCore Blazor libraries version 6.0.10.

Comment: I get the same type errors from Google search console (reporting a mobile browsing issue). The site works fine browsing manually, so I'm curious what causes this issue.